# Alternative argument in Fisher's exact test in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, fishers-exact-test

Can anyone please tell me what the `alternative` argument is in `fisher.test()` in R? What do greater and less imply?

```
fisher.test(x, y = NULL, workspace = 200000, hybrid = FALSE,
            control = list(), or = 1, alternative = "two.sided",
            conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95,
            simulate.p.value = FALSE, B = 2000)
```

I tried the help section and all it says is that alternative hypothesis must be one of `"two.sided", "greater", or "less"`. When should I use each one? I'm looking at over-representation in my set against a control set.

Answer (score 3):

This is the alternative hypothesis, commonly denoted by $H_1$. 
For example if you type or=1 and alternative=less, the $H_1$ hypothesis is $\psi<1$ where $\psi$ is the odds ratio (or).

Comment: I'm working on finding over-representation of a motif in my DNA sequences as compared to a background set. Let's say hypothetically that or=1 what should my alternative hypothesis be?from what I understand I want to know that this motif is enriched in my sequences but the null hypothesis would be that it is the same in both my set and background set. What do I use as an alternative in that case? do we select less or greater when we want to see over-representation? I'm confused in that part. In other words is there a need to select alternative or can the test be performed without it?Many thanks

Comment: You have to learn the basic principles of hypothesis testing ! If you want to prove that the odds ratio is significantly greater than 1 then you must use "greater" for the alternative hypothesis.